# Can't figure out how to use a variable from one function in another - Python

Tags: python, function, file, variables, tkinter

I am working on a small project to help me consolidate my learning of python. After endless trial with global variables, and returns; and searching I have decided to post here. Basically when the program is running, the user can select a .txt file from their computer and then the directory is recorded through the findFile() function specifically the my_label variable. I want to use the string stored in my_label to place it in the editFile function specifically the line: my_file = open("File location goes here","a+") in which it would look like my_file = open(my_label,"a+"). If anyone could provide help I would greatly appreciate it.

```
root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

def editFile ():

    x1 = entry1.get()

    label1 = tk.Label(root, text=x1 )
    canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)

    my_file = open("File location goes here","a+")

    my_file.read()

    my_file.write("\n" + x1)

    my_file.close()

def findFile ():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:\\Users\\mypc", 
title="Select A File", filetypes=(("txt files", "*.txt"),("All Files", "*.*"))) 
    my_label = Label(root, text=root.filename).pack() 
    canvas1.create_window(200, 290, window=my_label)

button1 = tk.Button(text='Enter Text', command=editFile)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

button2 = tk.Button(text='Exit', command=root.destroy)
canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=button2)

button3 = tk.Button(text='Find File', command=findFile)
canvas1.create_window(200, 270, window=button3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: in `my_label` you don't store any string nor `Label` but `None` because `pack()` always returns `None`. You have to do it in two steps `my_label = tk.Label()` and `my_label.pack()`. But you have your text in `root.filename` so use it in `editFile`.

Comment: ***"After endless trial with global variables, and returns"***: Read [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/7414759) to get rid of using `global`.

Comment: if you put widget (`my_label') on Canvas then you don't need `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `findFile()` you should use `global filename` to put value in global variable `filename` instead of creating local one.

In `editFile()` you don't have to use `global` because you only read value from variable.

But it is good to set default value at start `filename = ''` so you can check if filename was selected, and it will not raise error `"variable doesn't exist"`.

---

BTW: at start I created labels without text and later I change text in existing labels instead of creating label again and again when different files will be selected.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def editFile():
    #global filename # doesn't need to get value from global variable

    print(filename)

    text = entry1.get()

    # update text in existing `Label`
    label_text['text'] = text

    if filename: # dont't write if filename is not selected
        my_file = open(filename, "a")
        my_file.write("\n" + text)
        my_file.close()
    else:
        print('no filename')

def findFile():
    global filename # inform function to put value in global variable instead of creating local one

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="C:\\Users\\mypc", 
        title="Select A File",
        filetypes=(("txt files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*"))
    )

    # update text in existing `Label`
    label_filename['text'] = filename

# --- main ---

filename = '' # (global variable) default value at start

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

button1 = tk.Button(text='Enter Text', command=editFile)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

button2 = tk.Button(text='Exit', command=root.destroy)
canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=button2)

button3 = tk.Button(text='Find File', command=findFile)
canvas1.create_window(200, 270, window=button3)

# create only once and without text
label_filename = tk.Label(root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 290, window=label_filename)

# create only once and without text
label_text = tk.Label(root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label_text)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you furas you helped out a bunch. It works well and you helped me with formatting and better understanding the code you wrote. =)